# How to use JSplumb within meteor project (meteor project release 0.6.5.1)

Tags: jquery, meteor, jsplumb

I'd like to use `jsPlumb` in my meteor project. When I looked at the web, I saw that you can include it with `meteor add jsplumb:jsplumb` command. However, I'm running my meteor project with `mrt --release 0.6.5.1` flag. Therefore, I think I couldn't use it. Is there any way to add jsPlumb into my project?

**Edit**

As suggested, I put JsPlumb-1.7.10.js under client/compatibility. Then I've created a file named `flowchart.js` and its content is :

```
jsPlumb.ready(function() {
  jsPlumb.setContainer($('#container'));

  var i = 0;
  $('#container').dblclick(function(e) {
    var newState = $('<div>').attr('id', 'state' + i).addClass('item');

    var title = $('<div>').addClass('title').text('State ' + i);
    var connect = $('<div>').addClass('connect');

    newState.css({
      'top': e.pageY,
      'left': e.pageX
    });

    newState.append(title);
    newState.append(connect);

    $('#container').append(newState);

    jsPlumb.makeTarget(newState, {
      anchor: 'Continuous'
    });

    jsPlumb.makeSource(connect, {
      parent: newState,
      anchor: 'Continuous'
    });

    jsPlumb.draggable(newState, {
      containment: 'parent'
    });
    newState.dblclick(function(e) {
      jsPlumb.detachAllConnections($(this));
      $(this).remove();
      e.stopPropagation();
    });

    i++;
  });
});
```

and my `flowchart.html` file is :

```
<template name="flowchart">
<style type="text/css">
      .item {
        position: absolute;
        border: 1px solid black;
        background-color: #ddddff;
      }
      #container {
        border: 1px solid gray;
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
      }

    .title {
      padding: 10px;
      cursor: move;
    }

    .connect {
      width: 100%;
      height: 20px;
      background-color: white;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    </style>
    <div id="container"></div>
</template>
```

But when I go to `http://localhost:3000/flowchart` I got the following error :

```
Uncaught ReferenceError flowchart.js: jsPlumb is not defined
```

What might cause this problem?

By the way this is the example that I've found [here](https://github.com/EmielH/jsplumb-examples/blob/master/getting-started-2.html)

Comment: I highly recommend upgrading to the latest version of Meteor. You're about a year behind on 0.6.5.1 and there are so many packages you can't take advantage of

Comment: @EliezerSteinbock thank you for your recommendation but since I'm using an existing project which relies on this version of meteor, I cant upgrade. Do you know a solution to my question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't need to use the jsplumb meteor package to add it. Take the jsPlumb-1.7.10.js file and stick it in a folder called `client/compatibility`.

A better solution is updating Meteor. It is doable.

Comment: I've found `jquery.jsPlumb-1.6.0.js` in [here](https://github.com/jsplumb/jsplumb.github.io/tree/master/js) and put it under client/compatibility. Does it work?

Comment: I've edited my question could you check it out please  ? This is my first js application so my error might be trivial .

Comment: Where is the flowchart.js file? It should also be on the client. Stick it in the `client` folder

Comment: lib loads before compatibility. try sticking it in client

Comment: And also try changing the js code to this: `Template.flowchart.rendered(function() { jsPlumb code here... });`

Comment: is there any way to put flowchart.js file under client/lib? I asked it because there is a mxClient.js file under compatibility folder and there is a file which uses mxClient and its under client/lib folder.